# Android : SharedPreferences not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I just implement a `SharedPreferences`.

**Here's my Java code**

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("adsBannerFull", MainHelloballi.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isItFirstTime", true);
    editor.commit();

    if (sp.getBoolean("isItFirstTime", false)){
    closeButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.close_button);
    adsbannerFull = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.adsbanner_full);
    adsbannerFull.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adsbannerFull.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }); 

    adsbannerFull.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true); 
    adsbannerFull.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    adsbannerFull.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
    adsbannerFull.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
    adsbannerFull.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    adsbannerFull.loadUrl("http://api.hellobaliapps.com/ads/main_ads_big");
    }
    else {
        adsbannerFull = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.adsbanner_full);
        adsbannerFull.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

I put this code on `onCreate`. 
So at the first time the X `Activity` called it will show the `adsbannerFull`, but when the user go to Y `Activity` then go back to X `Activity` the `adsbannerFull` not show again.

I follow this guide http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126&aaid=146 and I make a improvement. But its not working, yet there's no error.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Here what your doing is always wright the isItFirstTime to true and than after doing this applying the if condition! Why?. Rather writing to the SharedPreferences first check if the isItFirstTime is null or not, if it's null than write it otherwise just switch to the if condition.

Comment: like this guide?

http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2012/04/12/android-how-to-execute-some-code-only-on-first-time-the-application-is-launched/

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("adsBannerFull", MainHelloballi.MODE_PRIVATE);

/* Initially, sp would be null and later on, sp.getBoolean would be false.
   If sp is null or sp.getboolean is true, the below statement block would be executed.
*/

if (sp.getBoolean("isItFirstTime", true)){

/*First time only this statement block would be called. 
All other times this statement block would never be called.*/
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isItFirstTime", false);
editor.commit();

closeButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.close_button);
adsbannerFull = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.adsbanner_full);
// Remaining code here .........

}// End of if block

/// Remaining code here..........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

Declare :

```
  private SharedPreferences prefs;
  private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

initialize :

```
 prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 editor = prefs.edit();
```

put value :

```
editor.putBoolean("isItFirstTime", true);
editor.commit();
```

get whenever you want :

```
 Boolean bool_val=prefs.getBoolean("isItFirstTime",false);
```

now you check your condition :

```
 if(bool_val)
 {
     true_Value;
 }
 else
 {
    false_Value;
 }
```

if needed check using System.out.println(...);